# Get text value from GetEnumSelectList<> not the Index value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

GetEnumSelectList<> is returning an Index value and not the text value. How do get the text value?

```html
Usage: 
<select asp-for="Policy" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList(typeof(PolicyEnum))" class="form-control"></select>

Results:
<select class="form-control" id="Policy" name="Policy">
  <option value="0">SuperAdmin</option>
  <option value="1">Admin</option>
  <option value="2">User</option>
  <option value="3">ClientAdmin</option>
  <option value="4">ClientUser</option>
</select>

Desired Results:
<select class="form-control" id="Policy" name="Policy">
  <option value="SuperAdmin">SuperAdmin</option>
  <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
  <option value="User">User</option>
  <option value="ClientAdmin">ClientAdmin</option>
  <option value="ClientUser">ClientUser</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please add the code causing the issue and actual/ expected result to further clarify the question.

Answer (score 2):

This works in .Net 6 used in a select tag:

```
asp-items="@Html.GetEnumSelectList<StatusEnum>().Select(si=>{si.Value=((StatusEnum)int.Parse(si.Value)).ToString(); return si;})"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need `SuperAdmin`, you could define the extenstion below:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetEnumValueSelectList<TEnum>(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper) where TEnum : struct
    {
        return new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)).OfType<Enum>()
            .Select(x =>
                new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = x.ToString(),
                    Value = x.ToString()
                }), "Value", "Text");
    }       
}
```

And useage:

```
<select asp-items="Html.GetEnumValueSelectList<PolicyEnum>()" class="form-control"></select>
```

If you need `[EnumMember(Value = "Admin")]`, you could try

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetEnumMemberSelectList<TEnum>(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper) where TEnum : struct
    {
        return new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)).OfType<Enum>()
            .Select(x =>
                new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = x.EnumMemberValue(),
                    Value = x.ToString()
                }), "Value", "Text");
    }

    public static string EnumMemberValue(this Enum value)
    {
        FieldInfo field = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

        EnumMemberAttribute attribute
                = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(field, typeof(EnumMemberAttribute))
                    as EnumMemberAttribute;

        return attribute == null ? value.ToString() : attribute.Value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to decorate you enum with a Description attribute
example

    `public enum SomeEnum
    {
         [Display(Name="First")]
         First = 1,
         [Display(Name="Second")]
         Second = 2
    }`

Comment: I have tried that and this.

    public enum PolicyEnum
    {
        [EnumMember(Value="SuperAdmin")]
        SuperAdmin,
        [EnumMember(Value = "Admin")]
        Admin,
        [EnumMember(Value = "User")]
        User,
        [EnumMember(Value = "ClientAdmin")]
        ClientAdmin,
        [EnumMember(Value = "ClientUser")]
        ClientUser
    }

Answer (score 0):

After decorate your Enum with description, you can use it:

```
internal static string GetDescription(Enum value)
{
    var attributes = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString()).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
    return attributes.Length == 0 ? value.ToString() : ((DescriptionAttribute) attributes[0]).Description;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
<select asp-for="Policy" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList(typeof(PolicyEnum))" class="form-control"></select>
```

Use this:

```
<select asp-for="Policy" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<Enums.PolicyEnum>()" class="form-control"></select>
```

and keep the Display for enum.

```
public enum PolicyEnum
{
     [Display(Name="First")]
     First = 1,
     [Display(Name="Second")]
     Second = 2
}
```

From MVC5.1, you can use this helper as well:

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.PolicyEnum, null, new { @id = "ddlPolicyEnum", @class = "form-control", @style = "width:200px;" })
```